# Where do I put the changelog to display the recent changes to the user?

Tags: version-control

I want to create a changelog for my application to display the set of recent changes to the user. But I'm not sure where I put it.

Do I create a text file and write in it? Where do I put this text file then?
Or do I use an action in the menubar and display the changelog in a new window when clicking on the action?

Comment: Are you asking how your application should display the set of recent changes to the user?

Comment: @DanPichelman Yeah, exactly.

Comment: I am not sure you should show the `ChangeLog` to every user. It is too detailed (there would be hundreds of commits between consecutive releases). You need to write your own `NEWS` file which summarize the ChangeLog file.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your changelog should be generated from version control checkins. You could have a post-build operation that pulls all checkin comments since the last release build and outputs to a file before packaging.

This requires your developers be diligent in their commits.

In the past, I have used conventions where commits starting with `CHANGE:` or `CHANGELOG:` are the only ones included in the output changelog.

This provides a good historical view without external maintenance.

**EDIT**

Since it seems you are simply asking how you should display it, you need to provide some context - What type of app, language, environment. Try something and then go ask on StackOverflow if you run into specific problems.

Typically, applications will link to the changelog in the about or help window along with the current version. The link could open a viewer for the changelog or link to a url containing the change history anchored to the version requesting it.